# Solutions on snaptell-like Image recognition and comparison to product database records

Tags: c#, comparison, image-recognition, sift, surf

I am looking for a solution VERY similar to what you get if you've used the iphone app "SnapTell". You take a picture of something and retrieve the actual image of it and prices, details, and properties of the product.

**The Situation:**
     I'm working on developing a machine and software combination for my company. The machine snaps a picture of print products (gift cards, greeting cards, photos, etc) of a fixed size and compares it to a database of 50,000 images that are nice quality well cropped scans of the product. It decides what the record in the database that the product is and makes decisions from there based on the images other properties in the database (price, market, what to do with it etc...)

- The images might be at different sizes (take up different percentages
  of the page)
- The images might be rotated
- The images might be at different scale (some might be zoomed in
  portions of similar objects).

**The Problem**
The products tend to be valuable and cannot be marked by bar-codes and such so image recognition is my only option at the moment. The end result application is being written in c# .net. I'm looking for a way to take one image and with a very high degree of accuracy and speed compare a snapshot to a database of images.

**Current line of thinking**
in my research I ran across SIFT then SURF. I was thinking if I broke each original high quality image up into high priority sections or say a grid of 9x9 sections then stored the SURF descriptors for each section in the database with a numerical score of some kind. then I could do the same to the new incoming product that gets a picture snapped.

I could break that up the same way and search the database by it's various SURF descriptors or something.

Am I even on the right track? Are there libraries out there for this sort of thing?

HELP!